# How to while loop a list (reading each line untill the end) without saving the list as a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script

The command below will give me a list of users not with a 1 day min password life. This works correctly.

```
awk -F: '$4 < 1 {print $1}' /etc/shadow
```

I want to take this list, and run...

```
chage -m 1 $p
```

where $p is the username on each line.

Normally, i would save this list as a file, and then run a while loop against it. See below for my full command to change all users to 1 day min password.

```
mkdir ./tmp
awk -F: '$4 < 1 {print $1}' /etc/shadow > ./tmp/usernamelist

while read p; do
      chage -m 1 $p
done <./tmp/usernamelist

rm -rf ./tmp/usernamelist
```

**Is there a way to do the same thing logically, but without having to save a file? Is this best practice?**

I would think there would be a way to do this with a pipe command, but i can't find a proper way to structure it.

Comment: Or just call `system` from within awk, since reading shadow requires root anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either with a pipe

```
awk -F: '$4 < 1 {print $1}' /etc/shadow |
while read p; do
      chage -m 1 "$p"
done
```

or with process substitution

```
while read p; do
      chage -m 1 "$p"
done < <(awk -F: '$4 < 1 {print $1}' /etc/shadow)
```

Comment: So you can just pipe data into the while loop like that and it'll read it as if it is reading a file?

I confirm this works.

Comment: @TrevorKS yes `read` reads the standard input stream, whether that comes by input redirection from a file (or process) or via a pipe

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '$4 < 1 {print $1}' /etc/shadow | xargs -r -L 1 chage -m 1
```

The `-L 1` ensures that each line of the awk output is passed to a separated *chage* invocation, and the `-r` ensures that *chage* is not run executed if awk doesn't output anything (which, admittedly, is quite unlikely in this case).